Why does nvim freeze when pressing Ctrl+Z+U simultaneously in gnome-terminal?
It sometimes occurred that Neovim froze after I pressed some key combination by accident (not Ctrl + S), meaning that it did not seem to react to any keyboard or mouse input (also not Ctrl + C and Ctrl + Z) and did not update the terminal display. The only way I found to recover was to kill the nvim process with SIGKILL.
Now it happened again and I finally learned that it was triggered by Ctrl + Z + U (which I probably hit accidentally when I try to use Ctrl + Z to switch the nvim process to the background, using a German keyboard layout, where the U key is next to the Z key).
I now had the chance to narrow down the problem:

It only happens with Neovim, not with Vim.
It also happens when running nvim --clean.
It only happens when U and Z are pressed sufficiently "simultaneously" (I would say within 0.1 seconds).
It happens reliably in GNOME Terminal, and very rarely also in Kitty (maybe the "sufficiently simultaneously" requirement is more strict in Kitty).
I tried to debug it by attaching strace to the nvim process (strace -p <pid>), this prevented it from happening (the key combination returned me to the terminal and moved the process to the background instead).

This is my environment:

Debian:
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Release:        12
Codename:       bookworm


GNOME Terminal:
$ gnome-terminal --version
# GNOME Terminal 3.46.8 using VTE 0.70.6 +BIDI +GNUTLS +ICU +SYSTEMD


Neovim:
$ nvim --version
NVIM v0.8.3
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3
Compiled by runner@fv-az183-550



What does the Ctrl + Z + U combination do that causes the freeze? Is there a way to recover without killing the process? Is there a way to prevent it other than using a different terminal?

Your question look more like a bug report. I suppose you'll have better chance by reporting that problem in the Neovim issue tracker

I don't know yet what it is a bug of, Neovim or GNOME Terminal? And maybe it's not a bug but just a feature I'm unaware of or don't understand. But fair point.

If it is a feature it look contrived ;-) But I understand your point, maybe someone here has an explanation. I would already start both thread ;-) (just my opinon)

I'd suggest trying a newer Neovim release, 0.10.1 is the latest official but you could try one of the nightly builds as well, perhaps that will have fixed the issue for you?
